# WebStorm Emmet interpretation padding element names with unwanted whitespace

Tags: whitespace, webstorm, emmet, jsx

For example, `span>strong` expands incorrectly to: `< span > < strong > < / strong > < / span >`

I'm using JSX Harmony, WebStorm 2016.1.1, ES6

[image]

Comment: 1) Try latest 2016.1.2 version; 2) Based on the colors alone ... everything after first `</ul>` does not seem to be treated as HTML for whatever reason (there seems to be an error marked just after that tag -- see what it has to say)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The problem is JSX Harmony only supposed to have all markup wrapped in ONE element within the return statement.

As I see now, that is the reason the first time it doesn't have a problem, but then when it does is because there are sibling elements at the root level.